# How can i dynamically call a Proc in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Is there a method.send equivalent for proc?
eg:

```
def s a
a + 1
end
b = "s"
send b.to_sym,10 #=> 11
```

Is there something like this?

```
p = Proc.new{|s| s + 1}
d = "p"
*call d.to_sym,10 *
```

EDIT:
In response to mudasobwa's answer
I need to call the Procs from an array of methods.
eg:

```
ss = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

Is it possible in this case?

Comment: Why don't you put the procs in the array (rather than their names) ?

Comment: @roychri actually i have the methods inside a class and need to run each of these methods inside a popen3 block to send and receive output from popen3 and use the output as the parameter. these procs are multiline and almost like a method.

Comment: It would help to see what you got so far.

Comment: I get the feeling the names of those procs are not really important. If I understand what you mean, you just need to call them all everytime your popen3 has new stdout/stderr data, right?

Comment: @roychri they are kind of important because each of their names determine the type of modification they go through before being passed as a parameter in the array of methods.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this particular example:

```
p = Proc.new{|s| s + 1}
d = "p"
#⇒ *call d.to_sym,10 *
```

It would be:

```
binding.local_variable_get(d).(10)
#⇒ 11
```

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if you make that an answer, I'll vote it up.

Comment: @mudasobwa I just updated the question, I have the method names as strings inside an array.

Comment: @BA I do not see any difference between calling 1 proc and many procs.

Comment: @mudasobwa wow thanks. I think binding.local_variable_get is the way to go. I did this: `p = Proc.new{ |s| s + 1};d = ["p"];d.each do |s|; puts binding.local_variable_get(s).(10);end;` that is what i am looking for thanks. i will look more into binding.local_variable_get, this is new to me.

Comment: Local variables and explicit binding usage is **never a good way to go**. The proper way to go was shown by @SergioTulentsev. Once again, in Layman’s terms: you are doing it wrong unless you use a hash as suggested by Sergio.

Answer (score 17):

The other answers cover *the exact* question asked. But I say, it was a wrong approach. Don't do that runtime introspection. It brings no benefit. If you want to address your procs by name, put them in a hash and use "civilian-grade" ruby.

```
handlers = {
  'process_payment' => proc { ... },
  'do_this' => proc { ... },
  'or_maybe_that' => proc { ... },
}

pipeline = ['process_payment', 'or_maybe_that']

pipeline.each do |method_name|
  handlers[method_name].call
end
```

Comment: this proc i am using is almost like a method with multiple lines(I need to use that instead of a method because it has to run inside an open3 block and procs are more convenient there because the method definitions wont take the stdin,stdout from the main popen3 block ). Right now i am using eval to call the proc and its working fine but was wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: @BA: this way is a better way.

Comment: I like the phrase '"civilian-grade" ruby'

Comment: @BA I would like it if you would ask a question showing the problem you're trying to solve with open3, blocks, and procs.  There's almost certainly a simpler way to do it than what you are doing.

Comment: @WayneConrad: hopefully, someday I'll become rich and famous because of it :)

Comment: @WayneConrad because i thought it would be too much work for both me and the SO community. 
here is the code with the open3 part.  http://pastebin.com/ypn7Jye3

Comment: @BA If that's working code, it looks like it'd form the basis of a good question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6):

### Updated

Procs are objects, so you can store them in variables, arrays, hashs, just like any objects, and call them from those rather than by names.

If you need to make an array of procs, store the procs themself in an array, rather than the names of the variables you assigned them to. This way, you can pass this array around and call them all.

```
myprocs = []
myprocs << = Proc.new{|s| s + 1}
myprocs.each {|p| p.call(10)}
```

If you want to call them by names, use a hash.

```
myprocs = {}
myprocs["d"] = Proc.new{|s| s + 1}
myprocs["d"].call(10)
```

Comment: this is the default way, How can I call it when method names are in the form of strings?

Comment: @roychri: as for the "array of names rather than procs themselves", this could be useful in a configurable app. You put chunks of code in the app, name them, but the exact order is defined through a yaml file or something. No idea if that's the case here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there are around 10 methods and the order are right inside the ruby file.

Answer (score 0):

Using `eval` - bad practice, but as one of the possible solutions is:

```
p = Proc.new{|s| s + 1}
d = "p"
eval("#{d}[10]")
#=> 11
```

Comment: @Alex yeah i am using eval currently but was looking for a better way.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you must be kidding. `prepend Module.new def eval(*args) puts args.inspect; end end` and all your obfuscation is done.

Comment: @mudasobwa: obviously, the trick will not hold against such powerful tools, but good luck compiling it in your head. That's what I meant. :)